# ImageView not taking complete height and width of the parent in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a simple Drag and Drop application. I have a `GridLayout` with 3 rows and 3 columns. `LinearLayout` are the children of the `GridLayout`. Now I am dropping ImageViews inside those `LinearLayout`. I want to set the `ImageView`'s `width` and `height` as `match_parent` or to cover the complete `height` and `width` of the `LinearLayout` in which it is dropped.

Here is my code:

```
public class PuzzleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.puzzle_layout);

        findViewById(R.id.a0).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.b0).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.c0).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.d0).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.e0).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

        findViewById(R.id.row0col0).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.row0col1).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.row0col2).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.row1col0).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.row1col1).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.row1col2).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.row2col0).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.row2col1).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.row2col2).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    }

    private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                        view);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    view.startDragAndDrop(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                } else {
                    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                }
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

        private View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("Image name", view.getContentDescription()+"");
            }
        };

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    // do nothing
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    /**
                     * Change background of the layout where item is entering
                     */
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ECECEC"));
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    /**
                     * Change background of the layout back to normal once item is moved out of it
                     */
                    v.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(PuzzleActivity.this, R.drawable.layout_background));
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    //ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent(); // Removed
                    //owner.removeView(view);                         // Removed
                    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;

                    if (container.getChildCount() > 0) {
                        container.removeAllViews();
                    }

                    // Added the following to copy the old view's bitmap to a new ImageView:
                    ImageView oldView = (ImageView) view;
                    ImageView newView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                    newView.setId(oldView.getId());
                    newView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    newView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    newView.setContentDescription(oldView.getContentDescription());
                    newView.setOnClickListener(myListener);
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = container.getLayoutParams();
                    newView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    newView.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) oldView.getDrawable()).getBitmap());

                    container.addView(newView);                       // Changed to add new view instead
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    v.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(PuzzleActivity.this, R.drawable.layout_background));
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying below code to set the `ImageView`'s `width` and `height` inside the `DragEvent.ACTION_DROP` case. But its not working:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = container.getLayoutParams();
                    newView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    newView.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) oldView.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
```

Here is my Layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/kolamShapesLayout"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:columnCount="3"
        android:paddingTop="64dp"
        android:paddingBottom="64dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        app:rowCount="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row0col0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row0col1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row0col2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1col0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1col1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1col2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row2col0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row2col1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row2col2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/kolamShapesLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:columnCount="5"
        app:rowCount="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/a0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/a0"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/c0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:contentDescription="@string/c0"
            android:src="@drawable/c0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/e0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:contentDescription="@string/e0"
            android:src="@drawable/e0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/d0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/d0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/d0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:contentDescription="@string/b0"
            android:src="@drawable/b0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Currently the `ImageView` is not visible as I am dropping the `ImageView` inside the layout.

Answer (score -1):

check padding and margin in parent layout and image layout also check the size of image which is full fill parent layout

Comment: As you can see in the code. there is no margin or padding.

Answer (score -1):

Change width of `ImageView`

from

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Use Following

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/a0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/a0"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/a0"
    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: No. I didnt mean that. The `ImageView` which I am creating dynamically in code. That is not taking full height inside the `LinearLayout`